# Wordpress css file

Tags: wordpress

In http://chuaquanam.ca/wordpress/, would anyone know how to make the image banner in the top of the screen to cover the whole width of the screen which is 1350px (and not 920 px) ? I would like to make it become like this http://chuaquanam.ca/

When I put 1350 as width in the .css file, the image becomes repeatable which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

Please look in

> wp-content>>theme>>your current theme>>header.php

In normal WordPress theme you can add banner image their.

Answer (score 0):

Hey could you please try this one

```
header.main-header {
    background-image: url("http://chuaquanam.ca/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/cropped-TopMenu11.jpg");
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 95%;
}
```